# NMCLI and IWCONFIG show very different signal levels

Tags: networking, network-manager, nmcli

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and I keep losing WiFi connectivity. This is a headless setup so I do everything over the command line. While investigating my issue I noticed that the signal strength advertised by NMCLI and what iwconfig reports are very different.

```
$: sudo nmcli dev wifi list
SSID              BSSID               MODE             FREQ       RATE       SIGNAL   SECURITY   ACTIVE
'MyWiFi'          20:4E:7F:A9:FD:DB   Infrastructure   2412 MHz   16 MB/s    99       WPA2       yes

$: iwconfig
wlan7     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"MyWiFi"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: 20:4E:7F:A9:FD:DB Bit
Rate:72.2 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0 Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment
thr:off Power Management:off Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=61/100
Noise level=0/100 Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

As you can see nmcli publishes a signal strength of 99 while, once connected, iwconfig shows a much lower signal level of 61/100. So, if a user make a decision about the quality of the WiFi signal from nmcli's response their actual signal strength may be 40% lower?

```
$: nmcli -v
nmcli tool, version 0.9.8.8


$: iwconfig --version
iwconfig  Wireless-Tools version 30
Compatible with Wireless Extension v11 to v22.

Kernel    Currently compiled with Wireless Extension v22.

wlan7     Recommend Wireless Extension v16 or later,
Currently compiled with Wireless Extension v22.
```

Comment: I'm not at all sure the numbers are calculated in the same way or are even significant. I'd be more interested in whether Network Manager is controlling the connection when it's running headless, as well as what driver you evidently compiled to try to solve this.

Comment: I didn't compile any driver, this WiFi dongle is using the rtl8192cu driver. Network manager does manage the wifi interface.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you disable power saving in Network Manager. From the terminal:

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Restart NM:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Does this fix the problem? If not, try a better driver:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms linux-firmware
```

Reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: I have already disabled power saving for the rtl8192cu driver. However, it will not be easy to try other drivers for my situation. This device (and I plan on installing others) is installed in a static location. I had been using NMCLI's signal strength to decide where to install my devices but it appears that this may be a meaningless value. What I'd really like to know is whether a location is a good place to install by measuring the signal strength but I don't know what to trust.

Comment: I suggested that you disable power saving in Network Manager; that is different from the driver. I think the only reliable way to judge the best location is: http://www.speedtest.net/